# How can you choose the width of td elements and put the td elements in a css class?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to pick a specific width for a td element. When i use style such asd

```
<style>
td.ex{
   width:105px;
}
</style>
```

and then apply that to the td element like this

```
<td class="ex">

</td>
```

it doesnt do anything however if i do this

```
<style>
    td{
       width:105px;
    }
    </style>
```

it applies it to all td elements which is not what i want. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Targeting by classname works just fine.

```css
td.ex{
  width:105px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ex">asdf</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: or just use .ex so you can apply to different objects aswell

Comment: Agree with this answer. You might throw an `!important;` on the values just to make sure they over-ride any inline css that would conflict. `td{width:105px !important;}`

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! Email Signatures are a pain!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is not possible. You can't change only one `<td>`'s width, while others have different size, since all cells in a column must have the same size (if your table has only one row, this is true). You didn't show your HTML code, so we don't know if this is the case.

However, you can change each `<td>`'s padding one-by-one to whatever you want. This can also reduce the cell's size, but the `<td>` element will actually fit the column's width - which is similar to what you want, I think.